# init a const array with heterogenous data in rust

Tags: rust

As an exercise for learning rust, I want to implement a pokemon-style elemental-type-matchup program (for the sake of implementation, I'm only going to have 8 elemental-types).

I want to be able to reference each ElType as named constants.

I want all these definitions to be constexprs, not initted at runtime, so that they can live in a read only section of memory.

in C, I would do something like

```
enum Types {
    NORMAL, GRASS, FIRE, WATER,
    ELECTRIC, FIGHTING, FLYING, ROCK
};
const float MatchupTable [8][8] = {
    [NORMAL]   = { [NORMAL]   = 1., [GRASS]    = 1., [FIRE]   = 1., [WATER] = 1.,
                   [ELECTRIC] = 1., [FIGHTING] = 1., [FLYING] = 1., [ROCK]  = 1. },

    [GRASS]    = ...
    ...
};
```

One reason I do this as an enum and array, instead of structs, is because it makes it easier to use types as values that can index into an array, rather than having to do some kind of switch all over the place. This does mean that there's technically a chance of incorrectly using a value from outside the enum to index outside of the array, but in practice that shouldn't be a problem (see you in 20 years on the CVE).

Anyway, now I want to write the same code in Rust. But, there are a couple problems. The first one is not a big problem: Rust enums are not very much like C enums, they're much more powerful, so the actual closest thing, far as I can tell, is just regular named constants.

```
const NORMAL:   i8 = 0;
const GRASS:    i8 = 1;
const FIRE:     i8 = 2;
const WATER:    i8 = 3;
const ELECTRIC: i8 = 4;
const FIGHTING: i8 = 5;
const FLYING:   i8 = 6;
const ROCK:     i8 = 7;
```

having to manually assign values for them is kind of annoying, so maybe there's a better way, but that's not the main problem.

The main problem is it seems that Rust does not allow for this kind of syntax where I can do `{ [index] = value }`. So then how can I init my `const MATCHUP_TABLE: [[f32; 8]; 8]`? I could just do a big blob of magic numbers of course, [[ 1f32, 1f32, 1f32, ...] ...]), but that's really horrible, error prone, and hard to read. Is there a way to init the array using the named constants?

Comment: Rust enums are way more powerful than C enums indeed, but they can also fill the role of them.

Comment: I'd [go the `struct` route and just implement `Index[Mut]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=17ada832a7979124630e0ce7917e41bb)

Comment: @cafce25 This is not necessarily as efficient (historically LLVM had troubles optimizing this kind of code, sometimes succeeding, sometimes not). But wrapping the array with an `Index` implementation is a good idea.

Comment: The main problem seems to be initialization with `normal`, `grass`, ... tags before the values, not sure how you'd get that with arrays (even if wrapped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as I said in the comment, you can use an enum for this. Its variants will be assigned consecutive numbers (starting from zero), and you can retrieve the associated number with `as`: `Enum::Variant as usize`.

Second, Rust indeed does not support this C syntax for initializing arrays, but it does have const-eval more powerful than C's:

```rust
enum Types {
    Normal,
    Grass,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Electric,
    Fighting,
    Flying,
    Rock,
}
static MATCHUP_TABLE: [[f32; 8]; 8] = {
    let mut result = [[0.; 8]; 8];

    result[Types::Normal as usize][Types::Normal as usize] = 1.;
    result[Types::Normal as usize][Types::Grass as usize] = 1.;
    // ...

    result[Types::Grass as usize][Types::Normal as usize] = 1.;
    // ...

    result
};
```

This looks terrible compared to the C code, but fortunately Rust also has macros:

```rust
macro_rules! init_types {
    {
        $init:expr;

        $( [$key:ident] = $value:expr ),* $(,)?
    } => {{
        // Ensure there are no duplicates or missing entries.
        if false {
            const fn generate_fake_types() -> Types {
                loop {}
            }

            match generate_fake_types() {
                $( Types::$key => {} )*
            }
        }

        let mut result = [$init; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT];

        $(
            result[Types::$key as usize] = $value;
        )*

        result
    }};
}

enum Types {
    Normal,
    Grass,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Electric,
    Fighting,
    Flying,
    Rock,
}
impl Types {
    const VARIANTS_COUNT: usize = 8;
}
static MATCHUP_TABLE: [[f32; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT] = init_types! {
    [0.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT];

    [Normal] = [1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT],
    [Grass] = init_types! { 0.;
        [Normal]   = 1., [Grass]    = 1., [Fire]   = 1., [Water] = 1.,
        [Electric] = 1., [Fighting] = 1., [Flying] = 1., [Rock]  = 1. },
    // ...
};
```

And this has almost the syntax of the C code. The only awkwardness is the need to specify a start value, but this isn't a big deal, and can be worked around if needed.

Here's an even better version, with better safety than even the C version, since you cannot use a non-enum index by mistake:

```rust
pub struct TypesArray<T>(pub [T; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]);

pub trait ConstDefault: Sized {
    const DEFAULT: Self;
}

impl ConstDefault for f32 {
    const DEFAULT: Self = 0.;
}
impl<T: ConstDefault> ConstDefault for TypesArray<T> {
    const DEFAULT: Self = Self([T::DEFAULT; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]);
}

impl<T> std::ops::Index<Types> for TypesArray<T> {
    type Output = T;

    fn index(&self, index: Types) -> &Self::Output {
        &self.0[index as usize]
    }
}

macro_rules! init_types {
    {
        $( [$key:ident] = $value:expr ),* $(,)?
    } => {{
        // Ensure there are no duplicates or missing entries.
        if false {
            const fn generate_fake_types() -> Types {
                loop {}
            }

            match generate_fake_types() {
                $( Types::$key => {} )*
            }
        }

        let mut result = TypesArray::DEFAULT;

        $(
            result.0[Types::$key as usize] = $value;
        )*

        result
    }};
}

enum Types {
    Normal,
    Grass,
    Fire,
    Water,
    Electric,
    Fighting,
    Flying,
    Rock,
}
impl Types {
    const VARIANTS_COUNT: usize = 8;
}
static MATCHUP_TABLE: TypesArray<TypesArray<f32>> = init_types! {
    [Normal] = TypesArray([1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]),
    [Grass] = init_types! { [Normal]   = 1., [Grass]    = 1., [Fire]   = 1., [Water] = 1.,
                            [Electric] = 1., [Fighting] = 1., [Flying] = 1., [Rock]  = 1. },
    // ...
    [Fire] = TypesArray([1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]),
    [Water] = TypesArray([1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]),
    [Electric] = TypesArray([1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]),
    [Fighting] = TypesArray([1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]),
    [Flying] = TypesArray([1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]),
    [Rock] = TypesArray([1.; Types::VARIANTS_COUNT]),
};
```

Comment: This looks like pretty much what I'm looking for, but one last question: Is MATCHUP_TABLE const, or merely static?

Comment: @user973223 what would be the difference here? Both need a `const` function / expression to initialize, merely swapping `static` for `const` will give you one or the other. You probably want a `static` (single place in memory everything can refer to) instead of a `const` which just puts the literal value wherever you use it (very roughly speaking).

Comment: well, in C at least, static only implies that the memory location is fixed, but the object is still writeable. whereas const implies static but also prevents reassignment (and allows the compiler to locate it in a read-only area of memory if it wants). it's not really *important*, but it's the kind of fine grained control it's nice to know how to access.

Comment: @user973223 In Rust however, but `const` and `static` are readonly (`static mut` or `static` with interior mutability (e.g. a mutex) are writable), but `static` actually places the data in the executable, while `const` is more like C++'s `constexpr` and copies the data in each reference to it. You can however replace `static` with `const` and it will still work, should you need it.

Comment: @user973223 And both are initialized at compile-time, contrary to C.

Comment: @user973223 Edited with better version with no start value and indexing as per cafce25 suggestion.